# Sending row number to another function on click

Tags: javascript

I have a table and each row needs a click function.

I would like to send the row number and the text to another function.

When I click on a row it gives me the right text but for each row it gives the total number of rows. How would I give the number of the current row that is clicked?

```
var table = document.getElementById("orders");
if (table != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
            tableText(this, i);
        };
    }
}

function tableText(tableCell, i) {
    alert(tableCell.innerHTML + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering a common problem with JavaScript `var` scoping. The problem is that the variable is scope to the `for` loop itself and not to the block. That means that the variable keeps changing with every further iteration of the `for`.

You can easily fix that with ES6 `let`:

```
const table = document.getElementById("orders");
if (table != null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
            tableText(this, i);
        };
    }
}
```

(I changed the other variables for best practice, but it’s not really necessary.)

If you can’t use ES6 you can fall back to a self executing function like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = (function (i) {
           return function () {
              tableText(this, i);
           };
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Not as nice, though.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Cleaner_code_in_inner_functions

Answer (score 0):

Without going into it deeply, I suspect that the `alert` call evaluating the `innerHTML` and `i` together, such that you're getting an incorrect number on the `alert`.

I would also change:

```
tableText(this, i);
```

to explicitly say

```
tableText(table.rows[i].cells[j], i);
```

just to avoid any possible confusion. `this` could be evaluating to the javascript / html file itself